# Mapping entities' fields to the same column

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, code-first, ef-code-first

Using Model-first and Table-per-heirachy, I can create two classes that inherit from the same base class, and map a column in each of the two derived classes to the same table column so that I can 're-use' columns.

If I try that with Code-first, I get the following error: "Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'XXX' was already defined."

I assume that this is a bug in code-first?

Here is some example code:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
public class ChildA : Parent
{
    public Int32 ChildAProperty { get; set; }
}
public class ChildB : Parent
{
    public Int32 ChildBProperty { get; set; }
}
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Parent> Entities { get { return this.Set<Parent>(); } }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var childAConfig = modelBuilder.Entity<ChildA>();
        childAConfig.Property(p => p.ChildAProperty).HasColumnName("Property");
        var childBConfig = modelBuilder.Entity<ChildB>();
        childBConfig.Property(p => p.ChildBProperty).HasColumnName("Property");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your mapping code?

Comment: Ladislav, I've added example code.

Comment: Just curious, typically in TPH why are you pointing the same column to 2 different properties in the dervied classes. I doubt if it will work

Comment: It is just to save those few extra bytes really ;-) It does work OK when using Model-First and the EDMS designer, but not in Code-First